# Trying to prove the Wess Zumino invariance under a SUSY transformation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, supersymmetry, lorentz-symmetry, spinors

I have the Lagrangian density

$$L=-\partial_\mu \phi^\star \partial^\mu \phi - \bar{\chi}_R \gamma^\mu \partial_\mu \chi_L - \bar{\chi}_L\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu \chi_R.$$

where $\epsilon$ is the infintesimal parameter of the transformation.

And I want to show it's equal to a total derivative under the transformations I have been given:

$$\delta\phi=\bar{\epsilon}_L \chi_L$$

$$\delta \chi_L= \frac{1}{2}\gamma^\mu\epsilon_R \partial_\mu\phi$$

I think (but not sure) that the transformations of $\chi_R $ and $\delta\phi^\star$ are:

$$\delta\phi=\epsilon_L^T \gamma_0 \chi_L^\star$$

$$\delta \chi_R= \frac{1}{2}\gamma^\mu\epsilon_L \partial_\mu\phi$$

My first question is, why does this model have 3 terms? Since $\phi$ is a complex scalar field, it must describe the boson, and because $\chi$ is a spinor, it describes the fermion. Why does the fermionic field need two terms to describe it, while the bosonic field only needs 1?

When I vary the Lagrangian with these transformations, I get 6 terms, and they all seem to be incompatible, i.e. I can't make them cancel out or make them equal to a total derivative.

Here is what I found the variation of the Lagrangian density to be (as you can see there is also a problem with the up and down indices in places, but I'm not confident of how to fix this):

$$-\epsilon_L^T\gamma_0\partial_\mu \chi_L^\star\partial_\mu\phi-\partial_\mu\phi^\star\bar{\epsilon_L}\partial^\mu\chi_L- \frac{1}{2}\gamma^\mu\epsilon_L(\partial_\mu\phi)\gamma^\mu(\partial_\mu\chi_L)-\frac{1}{2}\bar{\chi}_R\gamma^\mu\gamma^\mu\epsilon_R\partial_\mu(\partial_\mu\phi)- \frac{1}{2}\gamma^\mu\epsilon_R\partial_\mu\phi\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu\chi_R-\frac{1}{2}\bar{\chi_R}\gamma^\mu\gamma^\mu\epsilon_L\partial_\mu(\partial_\mu\phi).$$

I've been stuck on this for a while, and I'd really appreciate any insight

Comment: Where did you get the Lagrangian from? It doesn’t look right.

Comment: It was written up and given to me by my professor for my bachelor thesis. A phd supervisor also had a look at it so I'd be surprised if there's a mistake, but it could be

Comment: You can look at the Wikipedia artcle on the Wess-Zumino model.  The write the complex scalar field  as two real fields, and combine the two Weyl fermions of your action into a single Dirac fermion. The SUSY trsanformations   are also given there in a slighly different notation, and maybe that will help you see what is going on. If all else fails, I recommend "Supersymmetry DeMYSTiFied"
by Patrick Labelle.

Comment: Not sure abour your conventions, but the kinetic terms for the fermion could be missing a factor of $i$, and possibly a factor of $1/2$ since I assume that is a Majorana fermion?